# Hiding columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to hide certain columns if `Row(8:8)` meets certain criteria. My `For Each` loop is currently not working. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
Sub hide()
' hide Macro
'
Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("F:BJ").Columns
        If Rows.Range("8") = "Test" Or Rows.Range("8") = "Test1" Then
            Column.rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If

    Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Range("F8:BJ8")

    If rng.Value = "Test" Or rng.Value = "Test1" Then
        rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If

Next rng
```

Comment: @Bond - I realize my response is *very* close to yours but I will leave it be as it removes case sensitivity and toggles the column back to visible if the value has changed.

Comment: @Jeeped - The more the merrier, if it helps the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you would want to unhide the columns if the value in row 8 was changed programmatically or otherwise.

```
Dim rng As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each rng In .Range("F8:BJ8")
        rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = _
            CBool(LCase(rng.Value) = "test" Or LCase(rng.Value) = "test1")
    Next rng
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rows and Columns ranges refer to the whole spreadsheet if you don't specify a range.

```
Sub hideColumn()

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("F:BJ").Columns
        If rng.Rows(8) = "Test" Or rng.Rows(8) = "Test1" Then
            rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```